# Bluetooth mouse and keyboard not working after automatic reconnect

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth

I have a strange and new problem. My bluetooth mouse and keyboard are reconnecting sometimes. That's annoying but not new, for some seconds the connection is gone and it reconnects. But for some days the reconnect doesn't work anymore. The mouse or keyboard does a reconnect, but the inputs aren't recognized anymore (can't move the mouse or can't type with keyboard). 
I have to restart the bluetooth service by `sudo service bluetooth restart` or to manually disconnect and reconnect the mouse or keyboard.

The syslog doesn't help, there are no messages if this happens.

Hardware:

- Dell XPS 13 9370 (Ubuntu 16.04 with latest HWE Kernel 4.15.x)
- Logitech G604 Lightspeed Mouse
- Logitech G915 Keyboard

Which logs can I check? Is somebody experiencing the same issue?

Btw, I also tried the older kernels of 4.15.x (because it's a pretty new problem), but it didn't work

EDIT: Meanwhile I enabled the bluetooth debug mode. This is the syslog output when this happens (in this case the mouse):

```
Apr  7 15:32:11 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/adapter.c:dev_disconnected() Device E9:28:3A:B5:8D:64 disconnected, reason 0
Apr  7 15:32:11 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/adapter.c:adapter_remove_connection()
Apr  7 15:32:11 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: plugins/policy.c:disconnect_cb() reason 0
Apr  7 15:32:11 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/adapter.c:bonding_attempt_complete() hci0 bdaddr E9:28:3A:B5:8D:64 type 2 status 0xe
Apr  7 15:32:11 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:device_bonding_complete() bonding (nil) status 0x0e
Apr  7 15:32:11 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:device_bonding_failed() status 14
Apr  7 15:32:11 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/adapter.c:resume_discovery()
Apr  7 15:32:11 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:att_disconnected_cb()
Apr  7 15:32:11 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:att_disconnected_cb() Function not implemented (38)
Apr  7 15:32:11 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/gatt-client.c:btd_gatt_client_disconnected() Device disconnected. Cleaning up.
Apr  7 15:32:11 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: attrib/gattrib.c:g_attrib_unref() 0x56007959eed0: g_attrib_unref=1
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/adapter.c:connected_callback() hci0 device E9:28:3A:B5:8D:64 connected eir_len 0
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/gatt-database.c:connect_cb() New incoming LE ATT connection
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:device_attach_att() Elevating security level since LTK is available
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: attrib/gattrib.c:g_attrib_ref() 0x5600795a8500: g_attrib_ref=1
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/gatt-client.c:btd_gatt_client_connected() Device connected.
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() Read By Grp Type - start: 0x0001 end: 0xffff
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() MTU exchange complete, with MTU: 23
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() Read By Grp Type - start: 0x000a end: 0xffff
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() Read By Type - start: 0x0001 end: 0x0005
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() Read By Type - start: 0x0005 end: 0x0005
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() Primary services found: 6
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() start: 0x0001, end: 0x0009, uuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() start: 0x000a, end: 0x000d, uuid: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() start: 0x000e, end: 0x001c, uuid: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() start: 0x001d, end: 0x0020, uuid: 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() start: 0x0021, end: 0x0044, uuid: 00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() start: 0x0045, end: 0xffff, uuid: 00010000-0000-1000-8000-011f2000046d
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_client_ready_cb() status: success, error: 0
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:device_svc_resolved() /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E9_28_3A_B5_8D_64 err 0
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/gatt-client.c:btd_gatt_client_ready() GATT client ready
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/gatt-client.c:create_services() Exporting objects for GATT services: E9:28:3A:B5:8D:64
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x000e for device E9:28:3A:B5:8D:64
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x001d for device E9:28:3A:B5:8D:64
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0045 for device E9:28:3A:B5:8D:64
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() Read Req - handle: 0x0003
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/gatt-database.c:gap_device_name_read_cb() GAP Device Name read request
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() Registered handler for "Service Changed": 1
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() Read Req - handle: 0x0005
Apr  7 15:32:24 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: src/gatt-database.c:gap_appearance_read_cb() GAP Appearance read request
Apr  7 15:32:47 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: profiles/input/hog-lib.c:report_value_cb() HoG report (17 bytes)
Apr  7 15:33:42 pc123 bluetoothd[1006]: message repeated 40 times: [ profiles/input/hog-lib.c:report_value_cb() HoG report (17 bytes)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my Logitech MX Master too. It began occurring after bluez/libbluetooth3 was updated to 5.37-0ubuntu5.3. I reverted to 5.37-0ubuntu5.2 and all is good.

Comment: Thanks, for me it helped to also downgrade the bluez package to version 5.37-0ubuntu5 (I wasn't able to downgrade to 5.2 though)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Downgrading bluez to version 5.37-0ubuntu5 finally solved all my issues with my Microsoft Modern Mobile Mouse.